# Is there a similar tool as tcm / import for Azure Devops?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, azure-devops, testcasesource

I remember using the tcm /import tool a couple of years ago, to automatically create a test case that is associated to the unit test in the specified dll.
More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff942471(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Basically, it would automatically create a test case and add the associated automation to it.

Do you know if there is something similar for AzureDevops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such direct option under Azure Devops. But you could install [Test Case Association Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ilionx.AssociateToolTask) extension with pipeline. When you build your project under pipeline, and want to test the project, please add the task called Test Case Association to combine the file.

**Besides**, if it does not meet your requirements, you could [suggest a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) under DC Forum to report it.